# VB SMTP through System.Net.Mail stopped working

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, smtp, system.net.mail

I have a VB.NET application that sends emails to users letting them know something requires their attention.

The mail is generated within the app and sent through a Microsoft 365 Account.

This has worked for years without an issue, however 2 days ago it suddenly stopped working.

I have tested the mail account outside of the app and it works fine.

When I log in to the 365 account there are no items in the outbox or sent items for the last 2 days and no failed email notices in the inbox. Therefore I have concluded the issue must be somehow in the app.

The problem with this is that I have not changed this part of the app for about 2-3 years so don't know why it would stop working.

The code structure is:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub SendEmail()
        Dim MS365Email As New MailMessage
        MS365Email.To.Add("RECIPIENTEMAIL")
        MS365Email.From = New MailAddress("SENDEREMAIL")
        MS365Email.Subject = "SUBJECT"
        MS365Email.IsBodyHtml = True
        MS365Email.Body = "BODYTEXT"

        Dim MS365client As New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587)
        MS365Email.Priority = MailPriority.Normal

        MS365client.EnableSsl = True
        MS365client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Dim xms365 As New Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
        MS365client.Credentials = xms365
        MS365client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        MS365client.SendAsync(MS365Email, Nothing)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

JP

Comment: The same happened to me. Please check logging / exceptions. You have to enable SMTP (again) https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled

Comment: Thanks Markus, Instantly started working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same happened to me.
I had the following exception:

> Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant.
> Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information.

You have to allow SMTP for the account (again).
[Use Exchange Online PowerShell to enable or disable SMTP AUTH on specific mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission#use-exchange-online-powershell-to-enable-or-disable-smtp-auth-on-specific-mailboxes).

This example enables SMTP AUTH for mailbox sean@contoso.com.
`Set-CASMailbox -Identity sean@contoso.com -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $false`

[Outlook/Apps failing sending mails? Microsoft has disabled SMTP (July 2022)](https://borncity.com/win/2022/07/13/outlook-streikt-beim-mail-versand-microsoft-hat-smtp-deaktiviert-juli-2022/)